Meaning of セリフじゃない here
A is a smuggler (relatively nice compared to the other smugglers) who is tasked with moving a child of a noble Venezuelan family (B) to the clutches of a different competing family:

A: とりあえず食べ物投げつけるのはよしてくれないか
B: 口が腐るぞ
聖母マリア様はすべてお見通しだ悪党
A: まあこっちも片棒担いでて言うセリフじゃないのは分かってるよ
B: あんたさっきの入れ墨女や黒人の大男とは違うね
何だか普通の人みたいだ
A: だろうねまだ悪党見習いってとこなのさ
A: You can at least stop throwing food at me.
B: That friendly talk will rot
your mouth. Saint Maria can see through it, villain.
A: Well, I'm aware
that my words may not be appropriate... ...since I'm helping these
guys out.
B: You're different from the tattooed woman or the big black
man. You seem like a normal person.
A: It must seem like it. I'm just a
villain in training. [show's translation]

I find こっちも片棒担いでて言うセリフじゃないのは分かってるよ quite confusing. I think the breakdown is something like:
片棒担いでて - (I am) having a hand in [something bad]
言う - to say
セリフじゃない - (It's) not a remark, perhaps used like 「そんなことないでしょ！」where ない means something like "there is not something like that [under reasonable circumstances]" or something, hence the translation of "may not be appropriate" but I haven't heard this with じゃない, only ない. I don't know how these parts come together.
How should one understand this sentence?

What is your existing understanding of セリフ? "but I haven't heard this with じゃない, only ない" - well, what part of speech is セリフ? Therefore, how would it have to connect?

In this case it could mean "it's not (my) remark/line", it's not my line. But adding 片棒担いでて and 言う is still confusing as a relative clause, because I take it literally as "I also know it's not (my) "to say, having my hand in something bad" line". I get that relative clauses are flexible but I still find this confusing how it all connects. Also, I am unsure of the extent that セリフ means not just "one's lines", but literally "what one is supposed to say", as in what is reasonable. Rather, couldn't one take セリフじゃない to mean "it's not my line" as just that, expressing surprise?

This te-form is used to specify a temporal or conditional relationship. This "AしてBする" means "to A and then B" or "to B after doing A".

皮をむいて食べる果物
a fruit that you peel and then eat
a fruit you eat after peeling
実際に見て言えること
something you can say (only) after actually seeing it
片棒担いでて言うセリフ
a remark one would say after being complicit


まあこっちも片棒担いでて言うセリフじゃないのは分かってるよ。
Well, given my own involvement, I know I'm not in a position to say that.

